# Netfilter (230VAC) without protective earth (PE)

Tags: filter, noise, mains, emc, common-mode

I need to filter my mains input, but I don't have any protective earth (PE). Will a mainsfilter (schaffner for example) still be usefull?

I think so. I think the mains filter despite of not being connected to the PE will filter out some common mode noise. Differential noise is not filtered due to the absence of a low potential PE. Is this statement correct? Does this filter also help to reduce outgoing emission signals originating from components within the unit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the mains filter despite of not being connected to the PE will
>   filter out some common mode noise.

No it won't - it can only filter differential noise between the two wires.

> Differential noise is not filtered due to the absence of a low
>   potential PE. Is this statement correct?

No, common-mode noise cannot be filtered without a "common mode" reference point.

> Does this filter also help to reduce outgoing emission signals
>   originating from components within the unit?

It can only filter differential noise and if it's a pi type filter then it will filter in both directions.

Comment: Ah. Yes I mistakenly switched them. That's what I meant. Thanks.